# drupal 7 date field stores todays date even when user hasnt entered a value

Tags: datetime

I don't want it to! :-)

I'm using custom forms implementing a date field, then saving values manually to a node later. I could add an extra step preventing the value from being saved to the node, but I won't have the necessary info available to calculate whether to do this if it's an 'edit'.

Any ideas? I just dont want to save a value if the users doesnt enter anything. Seem's simple enough to me... :-S

Answer (score 0):

By [Form API reference](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#date) you need to manually set `'#default_value'` to prevent it from defaulting to `today`. So just add:

```
'#default_value' => NULL,
```

to your field's array to prevent it.

Comment: thought i had tried that. sometimes it's easy to lose track of what's been tried tho ;-) thanks ill go give it another go

Comment: @joevallender if that's not it, post relevant part of your form implementation. Or if you have time [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of it.

Comment: thanks, I'm actually working a significantly factored out proprietary set up of helper functions so it's a bit hard to communicate. it turns out this is no longer a requirement tho. oh well ;-)